# RSA for Websphere Software and Worklight Developer 6.2

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

On startup of RSA, even with a new workspace the following error pops up:

An internal error occurred during: "Installing Worklight Development Server".
Attempted to endRule: null, does not match most recent begin: R/.  See log for trace information if rule tracing is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Worklight 6.2 [supports RSA version 9.0 only](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/prodguid/v1r0/clarity-reports/report/html/prereqsForProduct?deliverableId=968A9CE03A2E11E396F9FC10E99BE807#sw-5). Please make sure that is the version of RSA that you are using. Other versions are currently not supported.

Comment: I originally had the following installed:

Comment: I first had RSA 4 WS 9.0 and Worklight Developer Studio 6.1. With this environment I managed to create some tutorial applications. I then tried to upgrade to Worklight Studio 6.2 by uninstalling 6.1 and then installing 6.2. I received the same the above error. I uninstalled everything and installed RSA 4 WS 9.1, Worklight Studio 6.2 and I still receive the above error. I have tried starting RSA with the -clean option, and a brand new workspace but the same error occurs.

Comment: All I know is that RSA 9.0 is the only officially supported version.